# How to fix CORS issue when deploying a 2 container docker-compose app to Azure and communicating between frontend and backend using REST API?

Tags: azure, rest, docker-compose, cors

I am trying to deploy a 2 container docker-compose app to Azure, consisting of a frontend and backend/api. I need the frontend container to communicate with the backend container using the fetch method to retrieve some data using REST API.

Once deployed I first get:

> "Blocked loading mixed active content “http://backend:9000/api/weather”"

then once I disable the protection temporarily, the error becomes

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend:9000/api/weather. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).".

This is my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    image: my_frontend_image
    build:
        context: .
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    environment:
      - PORT=8000
      - ENDPOINT=http://backend:9000/api
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
  backend:
    image: my_backend_image
    build:
        context: .
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      - PORT=9000
      - MAP_ENDPOINT=http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5
      - TARGET_CITY=Helsinki,fi
      - APPID=my_api_key
```

The frontend container exposes port 8000, backend container exposes 9000 in their respective Dockerfiles.

My backend is using kcors:

**index.js**

```
const cors = require('kcors');

const app = new Koa();

app.use(cors());
```

And the koa router:

**index.js**

```
const port = process.env.PORT;

const router = require('koa-router')();

router.get('/api/weather', async ctx => {
  const weatherData = await fetchWeather();

  ctx.type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
  ctx.body = weatherData.weather ? weatherData.weather[0] : {};
});

app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

app.listen(port);
```

My frontends request looks like this:

**index.jsx:**

```
const baseURL = process.env.ENDPOINT;

const getWeatherFromApi = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/weather`);
    return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  return {};
};
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const GLOBALS = {
  'process.env.ENDPOINT': JSON.stringify(process.env.ENDPOINT || 'http://0.0.0.0:9000/api'),
};

module.exports = {
...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
]
};
```

I managed to get the app working locally, by setting my api endpoint to http://localhost:9000/api and mapping "9000:9000" in my docker-compose. I cannot however get this to work in the cloud...

Locally, I tried pinging each container from within one another, which worked with no problem.

```
docker exec -it frontend bash
root@e87994510b0e:/app# ping backend
PING backend (172.25.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from backend.efi-recruitment_default (172.25.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
```

Trying to access the api using curl also worked:

```
root@e87994510b0e:/app# curl http://backend:9000/api/weather
{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}
```

This is the first time I'm trying to deploy something to Azure and I am quite lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Azure service are you using?

Comment: @CSharpRocks I am using the "Web App" service. "Web App for Containers" to be exact, it gets abbreviated to just "Web App" once created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **frontend** calls your **backend** from [user's browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Your **backend** is not exposed on the Internet and cannot be reached.

Place your backend in another Web App for container and update your URLs. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ended up doing this and my app was finally behaving as expected. I recommend any other beginner do this too, I wasted way too much trying to get it to work.